# When i reduce size to 480 px i want sidebar to move down and side bar content to move up using media query.?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

## maincontainer{

```
width: 100%;
float: right;
  
}
```

.first{

```
    float: left;
    width:50%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    min-height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size:24px;
```

}

```
.second{

    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: aqua;
    min-height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size:24px; 

}
```

I want the side bar content div to move up and side bar div to move down when i resize my screen to 480 px

```
@media all and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px)  {

.first{

    width: 100%;
    float: right !important;   

}

.second{

    width: 100%;
    float: left !important; 

}
}


<div id="maincontainer">

    
    <div class="first">Side Bar </div>

    <div class="Second">Side Bar Content </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You shoul describe more accurately your question: what is your actual problem?

Comment: If you view this code in 480 resolution you will see position of side bar div is top and position of side bar content div is bottom i want the opposite position of the side bar content div must be at the top and side bar div at the bottom using media query only.

Comment: Your document should be arranged semantically--the content that you want to appear first should be first in the markup. Then, use classes that are descriptive of their functions, not their order in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/1ssvwc3g/1/

Next time add a fiddle to your problem. Took me 1 minute to find another thread with your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27374063/1410735

```
#maincontainer { 
      display:flex; 
      flex-direction: column;
}
.first{ 
    order: 2 
}
.second{ 
    order: 1 
}
```

Comment: Content like your second paragraph really belongs in a comment, not an answer.